# Unable to set secure flag for cookies using $cookies.putObject in Angularjs version 1.4.4

Tags: angularjs, security, cookies

We are unable to set the secure flag for cookies using the $cookies service in Angularjs 1.4.4.
We are using the putObject() method mentioned in https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.4/docs/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies for the same.

Below is the same code snippet we are using for the same:

```
var config = {
    secure: true
};
$cookies.putObject('foo', 'bar', config);
```

We cannot see the secure flag being set when we inspect the cookie that's being created. 
Also, if we try to do a `$cookies.getObject('foo')` we get an undefined object in response. We already have all the necessary modules like "ngCookies" injected in our application.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is quite late but maybe others will find it helpful.

In angular 1.4.x and 1.5.x I set cookies like

```
let config = {
    secure: true
};
$cookies.put('foo', 'bar', config);
$cookies.get('foo');
```

To test the cookies you actually have to be on a secure connection - you will not be able to set or get secure cookies on localhost (unless you want to put some work into creating a secure localhost).